# iOS replaykit ,why didn`t have callback when user select "don`t allow " to record screen in ReplayKit

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

[image]

recently i found when user select the last one item [don`t allow]，but didn`t have any callback tell me ,cause the developer don`t konw which one user select it.

```
static private func startCapture(callback:@escaping(_ code:ScreenCheckStatus,_ msg:String) ->Void) {
        RPScreenRecorder.shared().isMicrophoneEnabled = true
        isCheckAuthAlreadStop = false
        startListenRefuseRecord(callback: callback)
        ///startCapture(handler captureHandler: ((CMSampleBuffer, RPSampleBufferType, Error?) -> Void)?) async throws
        RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture { buffer, bufType, error in
            if error != nil {
                callback(.startRecordError,error!.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                self.stopListenRefuseRecord()
                if buffer.isValid && CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(buffer) == true && !self.isCheckAuthAlreadStop{
                    self.stopCapture(callback: callback)
                    self.isCheckAuthAlreadStop = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static private func startListenRefuseRecord(callback:@escaping(_ code:ScreenCheckStatus,_ msg:String) ->Void) {
        ScreenCheck.isUserRefuseRecord = false
        let publisher1 = RPScreenRecorder.shared().publisher(for: \.isRecording)
        let publisher2 = RPScreenRecorder.shared().publisher(for: \.isMicrophoneEnabled)
        let cancelBag = Subscribers.Sink<Bool, Never>(receiveCompletion: { complete in
        }, receiveValue: {value in
            if !ScreenCheck.isUserRefuseRecord && value{
                ScreenCheck.isUserRefuseRecord = true
                callback(.resufeRecordError,"用户拒绝屏幕录制，请重新启动app，否则将导致屏幕录制失败")
                ScreenCheck.stopListenRefuseRecord()
            }
        })
        let latest = Publishers.CombineLatest(publisher1, publisher2)
            .throttle(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main, latest: true)
            .map{ !$0 && !$1}
        latest.subscribe(cancelBag)
        self.userRefuseRecordCancelBag = cancelBag
    }
```

how to konw why the replaykit don`t give callback when use select limits of authority ，and how to solve this problem ？

Comment: You should get an `error` value of [`userDeclined`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rprecordingerrorcode/userdeclined)

Answer (score 0):

If the user declines screen recording then you will get a [`userDeclined`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rprecordingerrorcode/userdeclined) error passed to your handler.

```
RPScreenRecorder.shared().startRecording() { error in
   if let error = error as? NSError {
      if error.domain == RPRecordingErrorDomain && error.code == RPRecordingErrorCode.userDeclined.rawValue {
          print("User declined screen recording")
      } else {
          print(error)
      }
    } else {
        print("No error")
    }
}
```

With `startCapture` the code is very similar; The error is reported to the `completionHandler` closure:

```
RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture( handler: { buffer, bufferType, error in
            //...
    },
    completionHandler: { error in
        if let error = error as? NSError {
            if error.domain == RPRecordingErrorDomain && error.code == RPRecordingErrorCode.userDeclined.rawValue {
               print("User declined screen recording")
            } else {
               print(error)
            }
       } else {
            print("No error")
       }
   })
```

Comment: I remember when the user doesn't allow it, there will be an error code, but now don`t have any callback, u can try it

Comment: i mean use "startCapture"  api

Comment: You have to provide the `completionHandler` closure.  See my update

Comment: thank u , as same as your say i try to test the code , the refuse callback in the completionHandler closure。Then you try to refuse again , don`t have any responce

Comment: In my testing the `completionHandler` was called with an error each time I tried to start capture and the user declined.

Comment: haha, ok for me i`m also tried to test replaykit，maybe we meet different situation，anyway thank u friendly help